# SQL select statement that checks two columns and returns the value from a third

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am writing a query that accesses multiple tables in the same database. For one of the columns in the select statement, I need to return

`Table1.Column4
 where Table1.Column = Table3.Column1 AND 
        Table1.Column2 = Table4.Column1`

I have it written as:

```
SELECT AccNum.FieldValue 
FROM  PersonFieldValuesVW 
INNER JOIN PersonFieldValuesVW AccNum 
ON AccNum.PersonId = InPerson.PersonId
     INNER JOIN InPerson 
     ON InPerson.IncidentId = Incident.Id 
WHERE AccNum.FieldDescr like '%Account Number%') as [Account Number],
```

This is returning the error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Here is the full query, any assistance would be appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CaseNum as [Case Number],
    ALCategoryVW.Category as [Category],
    ALCategoryVW.SubCategory as [Sub Category],
    InAssign.AssignToName as [Assigned To],
    ReportedDate as [Open Date],
    EndDate as [Closed Date], --This a placeholder for a closed date
    [Status],
    SiteLoc1.Descr as [Loss Location],
    LocDetails as [Loss Cost Center],
    SiteLoc1.Region as [Region],
    SiteLoc1.SubRegion as [Sub Region],
    -- SiteLoc2.Descr as [Location Description], **Need this though returning all for the location?
    CASE WHEN SAR.FieldId = '604NU' and SAR.FieldValue <> 'False' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as [SAR Required],
    Summary as [Incident Summary],
    Disposition as [Case Disposition],
    (
        SELECT AccNum.FieldValue
        FROM  PersonFieldValuesVW
        INNER JOIN PersonFieldValuesVW AccNum ON AccNum.PersonId = InPerson.PersonId
        INNER JOIN InPerson ON InPerson.IncidentId = Incident.Id
        WHERE AccNum.FieldDescr like '%Account Number%'
    ) as [Account Number],
    FORMAT(AuditItemDetail.ItemValue, '#,###') as [Potential Loss],
    FORMAT(AuditItemDetail.ItemValue - AuditItemDetail.PreventedExposureAmount, '#,###') as [Actual Loss]
FROM Incident
INNER JOIN ALCategoryVW ON ALCategoryVW.IncidentId = Incident.Id
INNER JOIN InAssign ON InAssign.IncidentId = Incident.Id
INNER JOIN SiteLoc1 ON SiteLoc1.Id = Incident.LocId
INNER JOIN SiteLoc2 ON SiteLoc2.SiteLoc1Id = SiteLoc1.Id
INNER JOIN IncidentFieldValuesVW SAR ON SAR.IncidentId = Incident.Id
INNER JOIN InItem ON InItem.IncidentId = Incident.Id
INNER JOIN AuditItemDetail ON AuditItemDetail.ItemId = InItem.ItemId
INNER JOIN InPerson ON InPerson.IncidentId = Incident.Id
INNER JOIN PersonFieldValuesVW AccNum ON AccNum.PersonId = InPerson.PersonId
```

Comment: did you read the error message? your subquery is returning multiple values in a context where it's allowed to return only one. e.g. 2+ records, and/or 2+ fields.

Comment: Why do you need a subquery there in the first place? You already have that table in your main query.

Comment: @MarcB - I see that but I am not sure how to return all the rows. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Maybe change the subquery to a join

Comment: In your first example query, you have extra text ") as [Account Number]," after the `LIKE '%AccountNumber%'`. Remove it and try that again.

Comment: I fail to understand all the down votes? Is the purpose of this site not to help those with programming questions and be a learning environment? If every question that was asked was by someone that knew everything then there would be no need for the site. I looked at the comment referenced above as a possible duplicate and asked anyway because I felt the two issues were not sufficiently alike to take that resolution.

Comment: @Kevin - People here can get bent out of shape when the answer seems obvious to them ("RTFM, NOOB!"). Don't take their negativity to heart. If there is a legit reason to close the question (too broad, not programming related, etc), it has to be voted on by at least 5 other users.

Comment: @Anthony Horne - I have reverted the question to Ghost's edit as yours made the entire question much more difficult to read. Please do not over-whitespace and cause excess scrolling.

Comment: @StingyJack NP.  I generally think it is better to see the full text without scrolling left to right AND up and down.  I also find that showing the output column aliases in line, makes it easier to read.

Comment: @KevinSchultz when you read a question that address the same error you're getting, and there is some difference that causes that answer not to help you, that is Exactly the kind of thing you should include when you post your question.   As posted, your question looks like you made no effort to research the error message, and that's the main reason people downvote here.

Comment: As far as the downvotes go, I think it's because you didn't clearly state what you wanted. I answered based on how I read the question and your comment clarified. For all SQL questions, it's always nice to include at a minimum the output columns and a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should resolve your error, but I'm not sure it is logically correct. If you have two records being returned in the sub-select, which one is the "right" one.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CaseNum as [Case Number],
    ALCategoryVW.Category as [Category],
    ALCategoryVW.SubCategory as [Sub Category],
    InAssign.AssignToName as [Assigned To],
    ReportedDate as [Open Date],
    EndDate as [Closed Date], --This a placeholder for a closed date
    [Status],
    SiteLoc1.Descr as [Loss Location],
    LocDetails as [Loss Cost Center],
    SiteLoc1.Region as [Region],
    SiteLoc1.SubRegion as [Sub Region],
    -- SiteLoc2.Descr as [Location Description], **Need this though returning all for the location?
    CASE WHEN SAR.FieldId = '604NU' and SAR.FieldValue <> 'False' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as [SAR Required],
    Summary as [Incident Summary],
    Disposition as [Case Disposition],
    AccNum.FieldValue,
    FORMAT(AuditItemDetail.ItemValue, '#,###') as [Potential Loss],
    FORMAT(AuditItemDetail.ItemValue - AuditItemDetail.PreventedExposureAmount, '#,###') as [Actual Loss]
FROM Incident
INNER JOIN ALCategoryVW ON ALCategoryVW.IncidentId = Incident.Id
INNER JOIN InAssign ON InAssign.IncidentId = Incident.Id
INNER JOIN SiteLoc1 ON SiteLoc1.Id = Incident.LocId
INNER JOIN SiteLoc2 ON SiteLoc2.SiteLoc1Id = SiteLoc1.Id
INNER JOIN IncidentFieldValuesVW SAR ON SAR.IncidentId = Incident.Id
INNER JOIN InItem ON InItem.IncidentId = Incident.Id
INNER JOIN AuditItemDetail ON AuditItemDetail.ItemId = InItem.ItemId
INNER JOIN InPerson ON InPerson.IncidentId = Incident.Id
LEFT JOIN PersonFieldValuesVW AccNum ON AccNum.PersonId = InPerson.PersonId AND AccNum.FieldDescr like '%Account Number%'
```

***Updated based on comment.

Comment: In this case, there may be many account numbers for a person, therefore I want all of them that match the other two columns.

Comment: Then you need to Join (allows 0-* matches) your account number data in, not use a subquery (assumes one match).